# PHP using regex to convert markdown similar syntax into image HTML tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I am creating some syntax similar to Markdown. Trying to convert the following syntaxes regardless of spacing between colons, attribute keywords, attribute values, or parentesis (the order of alt and class attributes shouldn't matter):

```
(image: profile.jpg alt: Michael class: profile)
(image : profile.jpg alt : Michael class : profile)
( image : profile.jpg alt : Michael class : profile )
```

all into img tag correctly like

```
<img src="profile.jpg" alt="Michael" class="profile">
```

The alt and class tag attributes won't always be used, so for example the following

```
(image: profile.jpg class: profile)
```

will become

```
<img src="profile.jpg" class="profile">
```

and the following

```
(image: profile.jpg)
```

will become

```
<img src="profile.jpg">
```

but sometimes the class values (or alt values) is comprised of more than one word like

```
(image: profile.jpg alt: Michael Jackson class: profile dark red)
```

and should become

```
<img src="profile.jpg" alt="Michael Jackson" class="profile dark red">
```

I have tried to do this but failed due to the spaces between the attribute key words and values, don't know how to select them using preg_match() and/or preg_replace correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use JSON as: `{"image": "profile.jpg", "alt": "Michael Jackson", "class": "profile"}`

Comment: @anubhava JSON is or YAML are not the options, because I am trying to create markdown syntax of my own in a script I am creating, so users can easily insert HTML tags in the text editor as much little typing as possible. I have used an editor like this in a software , so I am trying to replicate that feature. Thank you.

Comment: then why not use markdown? forcing your users to learn some custom markup language is pretty ... arrogant, when there's plenty of perfectly good markup languages already available.

Comment: @Marc B: I am not trying to reinvent everything, just trying to create some addition syntaxes to existing Markdown syntax, it's because this will assign the source of the markdown text file's URL automatically, so the images can be uploaded into the same directory where the markdown file is. The default Markdown syntax doesn't allow that obviously :)

Comment: What if an image filename contains spaces? What will your markdown look like?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split) function, and the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag you can include with it. For example, if each line of your input was `$line` and the parentheses were stripped out:

```
$pieces = preg_split('/(\S+)\s*:/', $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

`$pieces` will be an array like this:

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => 'image',
  2 => ' profile.jpg ',
  3 => 'alt',
  4 => ' Michael Jackson ',
  5 => 'class',
  6 => ' profile dark red',
)
```

Due to some foibles of PHP, you'll have to throw out the 0th element, but the rest of `$pieces` will have the strings you need.